# Date conversion in pandas csv reader

Tags: python, csv, pandas, converters

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

def addtime(temp):
    temp = (temp) + (dt.timedelta(hours  =16))
    return(temp)

data = """\
    '12-31-2012',5100, 5200
    '01/1/2013',5300,5400"""

tdata = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),
    names =    ['date', 'field1', 'field'], index_col = None,
    parse_dates =['date'], header= None)

print tdata

old_date = tdata.ix[0,'date']
print 'old date =',old_date
new_date = addtime(old_date)
print 'new date =',new_date

#                 date  field1  field
#0  2012-12-31 00:00:00    5100   5200
#1  2013-01-01 00:00:00    5300   5400
#old date = 2012-12-31 00:00:00
#new date = 2012-12-31 16:00:00
```

I would like to add 16 hours to each date as part of the Pandas CSV reader. but I can't figure out how to add a "parse_dates=" that works.  The sample code performs the operation correctly, just not in the desired manner. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `date_parser` parameter. Ordinarily, that defaults to `dateutil.parser.parse`, but you can specify a custom function (such as `addtime`, below) which not only parses the date string but also adds a `timedelta` as well.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import dateutil.parser as parser

def addtime(temp):
    temp = parser.parse(temp) + dt.timedelta(hours=16)
    return temp

data = """\
    '12-31-2012',5100, 5200
    '01/1/2013',5300,5400"""

tdata = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),
    names = ['date', 'field1', 'field'], index_col = None,
    parse_dates =['date'], header= None, date_parser=addtime)

print tdata
```

yields

```
                  date  field1  field
0  2012-12-31 16:00:00    5100   5200
1  2013-01-01 16:00:00    5300   5400
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't get/use the correct form for the parser statement you added to addtime.